# Taking Hyper-V Snapshots to a Network Location

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, snapshot

Is it possible to take snapshots in Hyper-V (on Windows Server 2008 R2) directly to a network location?  I want to set the Snapshot Location under Settings on the VM to \server\c$\StoreVMsHere.

We would like to take weekly snapshots and store them in a different location from the Hyper-V server.

Is this going to be a manual move situation, or can I snapshot directly to a different network location?

Comment: I don't think Hyper-V snapshots are what you think they are. They are not copies or backups. They simply create a new differencing disk to be the primary VHD, and link the existing VHD as the parent of the new differencing disk. (plus some stuff related to RAM, Configuration, and system state).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're really looking for a backup solution, not Hyper-V snapshots.  Use a backup utility for that.

Hyper-V does not support putting live VHD files on network shares (partly because VSS and the backup infrastructure isn't available there.)  And those snapshots have "differencing VHDs" within them that are used while the VM is running.